# LLDB: Python API StepInstruction - not stepping twice

Tags: python, scripting, lldb

I define a breakpoint by doing the following:

```
breakpoint = target.BreakpointCreateByAddress(loadAddr)
breakpoint.SetScriptCallbackFunction( "mylldbmodule.bp_hit" )
```

My bp_hit function is defined as:

```
def bp_hit(frame, *args):

    thread = frame.GetThread()
    process = thread.GetProcess()

    #
    # some work done here
    #

    #thread.StepInstruction( True )
    #thread.StepInstruction( True )

    # 
    # some more work done here
    #
```

When my breakpoint is hit, I can see that my pc is at loadAddr. If I have one of the StepInstruction calls executed, my pc is loadAddr + 4 when I view it. However, if both StepInstructions are executed, my pc is still loadAddr + 4 when I view it.

For some reason, the second (or even a third) StepInstruction has no effect on the pc.

Why? Is there something I can do to have this work as expected?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lldb stops the execution of the commands on a breakpoint after any command that restarts the debugee.  Doing this is a little tricky, since you could hit a breakpoint in the middle of the command that restarted the debugee, and then we'd have to re-enter the command interpreter - while in the middle of a breakpoint command.

It will take some more cleanup before lldb can handle this robustly, so we disallow it for now.

Depending on what you are trying to do, you might be able to invert the problem & drive the whole debugging session from Python.  If that seems a useful thing to do, there's an example here that might get you started:

http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/lldb/trunk/examples/python/process_events.py

Comment: Thank you. Would you happen to have an answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32192027/lldb-python-api-setting-callback-function-for-a-watchpoint as well?