# LLDB: Python API & Setting callback function for a watchpoint

Tags: python, scripting, lldb

Looking at the documentation for SBWatchpoint at http://lldb.llvm.org/python_reference/index.html, I do not see a method for assigning a python callback function for when a watchpoint is triggered.

Is there a way to do this with the Python API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a

```
watchpoint command add
```

command that supports doing that

```
  watchpoint command add [-e <boolean>] [-s <none>] [-F <python-function>] <watchpt-id>
```

If you have an SBWatchpoint, you can query for its ID, and then craft an appropriate command line to pass down to SBDebugger.HandleCommand

You will need your Python module to contain the script function you want executed, and pass it by qualified name on the command line. For instance, if you have

```
# myfile.py
def callback(wp_no):
   # stuff
# more stuff
mywatchpoint = ...
debugger.HandleCommand("watchpoint command add -F myfile.callback %s" % mywatchpoint.GetID())
```

would be the way to tell LLDB about your callback

Currently, there is no way to pass Python functions directly to LLDB API calls.

There is no reason why that is impossible, but it is a little tricky to get right in a world where multiple scripting languages could coexist, and given the lack of a viable alternative strategy, there's not much pressure to get it working.

Comment: It is interesting that SBWatchpoint doesn't have a way to pass in the python callback function directly, but SBBreakpoint does.

Comment: Not exactly. You can pass a function name, or a function body, but not a function object.

Comment: But, yes, a patch that extends those same provisions to SBWatchpoint would be very welcome